# ECDSA keys storing

Tags: .net, encoding, cryptography, ecdsa, key-pair

I am implementing ECDSA keys and certificates in .NET, and I need to store the keys so that I can reuse them with a new signing.
With RSA I was using the class RSACryptoServiceProvider, but I don't see anything similar with ECDsa neither ECDsaCng classes.

I only have seen DSACryptoServiceProvider and one old ECDsaCryptoServiceProvider to Framework 4.3 (a bit old).

Does anyone know a way to store ECDSA keys as in RSA, please?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean you would like to persist a key into the OS key store (RSACryptoServiceProvider using a named key), with CNG the interface is a little different:

```
private static ECDsa CreateOrOpenECDsaKey(string keyName)
{
    CngKey key;

    if (CngKey.Exists(keyName))
    {
        key = CngKey.Open(keyName);
    }
    else
    {
        // You can also specify options here, like if it should be exportable, in a
        // different overload.
        key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP521, keyName);
    }

    // The ECDsaCng constructor will duplicate the key reference, so we can close this one.
    using (key)
    {
        return new ECDsaCng(key);
    }
}
```

If you meant you want to do export/import like RSAParameters, that feature is present in .NET Core, but isn't yet present in .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is really useful. I have tried but in the return as ECDsaCng value I get an exception: "Keys used with the ECDsaCng algorithm must have an algorithm group of ECDsa.\r\nParameter name: key". My key was generated with BouncyCastle library and it seems that is created as ECDH instead of ECDSA. I have to find out in this side.

Comment: @santiPipes That's fixed .NET Framework 4.6.2 (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/ECDsaCng.cs,bab9826847a21b79)

Comment: I see, thanks so much @bartonjs. This means I must install new framework in all computers which this software is going to be executed, isn't it? I suppose this is not solved only compiling with Framework 4.6.2 (I know, silly question)

Comment: @santiPipes If your keys were created with BouncyCastle everywhere, then yeah :(.  If you let CngKey.Create create the key instead then it'll work on .NET 3.5 or higher.